# Helping a preschooler overcome fear and encourage trust

Tags: gymnastics

I run a preschool gymnastics program at a large gymnastics facility in my area. I have been the director for 4 years and have been teaching dance and preschool gymnastics for 9 years. Not once in my career have I experienced a child so deathly terrified of front rolls or having someone help them until now.

I have a very sweet and talented student who has no mental or physical disabilities that I am aware of. However this student refuses to try a front roll or looking up side down. No matter how much I encourage, demonstrate and try to guide, the student cries and almost has a nervous breakdown. I have used other students to show my fearful one that I will never let anything happen to them, that their safety is my only concern. However, there is no luck. I have broken down the skill into steps and they nail each one, until it is time to roll.

This particular student will not even allow their parents to help. So my question to you is, what can I do to help this student over come their fear and trust issues?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a psychological issue, and shouldn't be asked on the Internet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a psychological issue, and can't really be solved remotely.